# Host can only ping another host if fhe former is pinged first

Tags: networking, routing

I have one Ubuntu 18.04 laptop and one Lubuntu 18.04 laptop.

The Lubuntu laptop can't ping the Ubuntu laptop ("No route to host") until the Ubuntu laptop pings the Lubuntu laptop first (which works without problems) and then suddenly the Lubuntu laptop can ping the Ubuntu laptop.

Would this be related with route discovery or ARP on the Lubuntu laptop? What gives?

Comment: It's related to nothaving a "default" route. `ip route`. Look at your network logs `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbinNetworkManager`.

Comment: @waltinator 
`ip route` gives: `default via 192.168.1. dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp etric 600` which is correct. `journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` contains nothing having to do with routing problems.